# Hadoop Documentation for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, javadoc

I recently installed Hadoop and am able to run simple programs.

However I would like to view documentation for Hadoop classes within Javadoc browser in Eclipse.

Please let me know how to enable that (I am a little novice with Eclipse IDE).

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

- If you're using maven for your dependency management, you should be able to expand out the list of Maven dependencies in your Eclipse project, right click the hadoop-core-x.x.x.jar and select Maven -> *Download Javadocs*
- Otherwise you'll need to source the Javadocs from the $HADOOP_HOME/docs/api folder and associated with your hadoop-core-x.x.x.jar in Eclipse. In Eclipse, right click your Java project and select *Build Path -> Configure Build Path*. Now click the *Libraries* tab and locate the entry for hadoop-core-x.x.x.jar. Expand the entry to show options for Source, Javadoc etc locations and click the Javadoc location entry. Now click the Edit button to the right and enter the location as the path $HADOOP_HOME/docs/api in the Javadoc URL text box (mine is `file:/opt/hadoop/hadoop-1.0.2/docs/api/`)

Either way now you should be able to hover over Hadoop classes in Eclipse and the Javadoc will popup. You can also show the Javadoc window that will populate for the class you are currently viewing, or just open an internal browser window and point it at the $HADOOP_HOME/docs/api/index.html file

Answer (score 6):

Another easy solution for those who want to stay updated is to edit the Javadocs path like Chris said:

> "In Eclipse, right click your Java project and select Build Path -> Configure Build Path. Now click the Libraries tab and locate the entry for hadoop-core-x.x.x.jar. Expand the entry to show options for Source, Javadoc etc locations and click the Javadoc location entry. Now click the Edit button to the right and enter the location as the path"

but instead of linking it directly to the api you have stored on your hard disk, link it to `http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/`

Comment: This great thanks! I just wanted to add if your using Maven and it is not downloading Javadoc you can use @roy's answer too. You right click the project -> Properties -> Java Build Path, expand Maven Dependencies, expand the hadoop-core and set the Javdoc location to the link. Also you do not need to set it to the stable api if you're using a different one, you can pick from 

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs 

Just add api to the end of the version link, e.g. 

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/

Comment: Thanks! This was very useful. Infact, keeps my documents updated no matter what changes in the documentation!